# Foldleft in Racket

Tags: racket, foldleft

I have a question regarding trying to define a recursively defined foldl function in Racket.

Here is my approach:

```
(define foldl
  (lambda (z c xs)
    (match xs
      (empty z)
      ((make-pair x xs) (foldl c (c z x) xs)))))
```

Unfortunately, when I do this, I get the Error:

```
expected a function after the open parenthesis but received 1
```

I cannot quite figure out why this message is popping up. Can someone help me?

Comment: And your test example was?

Comment: (foldl 0 (lambda (x y) (+ x y)) (list %a)) as an example

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing is use to swapping the arguments to `foldl`.

Your definition is:

```
(define foldl
  (lambda (z c xs)
```

Here `z` is an element a `c` is a constructor.
In

```
(foldl c (c z x) xs)))))
```

you swapped the first two argument.

Note: You need to change the `match` patterns.

Change  `empty` to `'()`.
Change  `make-pair` to `cons`.